# How to find duplicate names in table when first and last name can be in a different order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find duplicate names from a table. Currently I have this query which does find some duplicate names.

```
select DisplayName, count(DisplayName)
from  table_name
group by DisplayName
having count(DisplayName) > 1
```

This will provide the display names that are exactly the same. For example if there are two "Richard, Michael" display names then they will show in the output. But, if there was a third display name that was "Michael, Richard" then that will not show with the current query I have.

Comment: No it won't because `Michael, Richard` and `Richard, Michael` are completely different names. As someone who has a Surname that is a forename (if you remove the s at the end, because to some people it's invisible) I can tell you that Richard would be really annoyed if you called them "Michael". Would you expect "Richards, Michael" to match "Michaels, Richard" too? I *really* hope not.

Comment: I see its for DisplayName, but usually if you have 2 different values in 1 field you have 2 separate fields in the database for them, then in the display layer, you can combine them.

Comment: I should clarify that some of the users have either created multiple accounts (two "Richard, Michael" example) as well as creating an account where they entered their display names as FirstName, LastName ("Michael, Richard" example). In this case Michael Richard is one person but has three different accounts created.

Comment: Ignoring the actual SQL logic to equate those 2 sets, how EXACTLY do you know that "Michael, Richard" is a duplicate of "Richard, Michael"? The sql logic is trivial (with a lot of assumptions about format) - you simply break apart the two values from the string ("split" - hint) and then aggregate / join / combine. But this smells like a kludge to a different [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: In this case yes it is incorrect to assume that Michael, Richard and Richard, Michael are the same person.

Comment: Aside: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with freestyle text not normalized correctly. There will be more logic required but grab a copy of [delimitedsplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) and you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @names TABLE (SomeName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @names 
VALUES('Richard, Michael'),('Sam Jones'),('Michael Richard'),('Bill Smith'),('Bill Smith');

SELECT 
  DisplayName = f.Nm,
  Total       = COUNT(f.Nm)
FROM   @names AS n
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT LTRIM(x.item+' ')
  FROM   dbo.delimitedSplit8K(n.SomeName,',') AS x
  ORDER BY x.itemNumber DESC
  FOR XML PATH('')
) AS f(Nm)
GROUP BY f.Nm
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1;
```

**returns:**

```
DisplayName                  Total
---------------------------- -----------
Bill Smith                   2
Michael Richard              2
```